# The page request for /admin/structure/block only returns part of the html and doesn't render it

Tags: blocks

I'm logged in to Drupal and am requesting the blocks page at /admin/structure/block.  However, the page request doesn't render properly in my browser.  (I tried two different browsers with similar results).

The page I get begins with this:

```
d90
>configure</a></td>
        <td><a href="/admin/structure/block/manage/block/356/delete" id="edit-blocks-block-356-delete">delete</a></td>
      </tr>
                  <tr class="draggable even">
        <td class="block">Set Free - FAQ 1</td>
        <td><div class="form-item form-type-select form-item-blocks-block-333-region">   <label class="element-invisible"
for="edit-blocks-block-333-region">Region for Set Free - FAQ 1 block
</label>  <select class="block-region-select block-region-user_first
form-select" id="edit-blocks-block-333-region"
name="blocks[block_333][region]"><option value="-1">- None
-</option><option value="help">He
```

Or this:

```
10000 ion><option value="map">Map</option><option
value="preface">Preface</option><option
value="breadcrumb">Breadcrumb</option></select> </div> <input
type="hidden" name="blocks[block_110][theme]" value="omnia" /> </td>
        <td><div class="form-item form-type-textfield form-item-blocks-block-110-weight">   <label class="element-invisible"
for="edit-blocks-block-110-weight">Weight for 30 DIGITAL TALENTS -
Home Corprate block </label>  <input class="block
```

or this:

```
a46c t form-select" id="edit-blocks-block-366-region"
name="blocks[block_366][region]"><option value="-1">- None
-</option><option value="help">Help</option><option value="content">Content</option><option value="top_first">Top
First</option><option value="top_second">Top Second</option><option
value="top_third">Top Third</option><option value="top_fourth">Top
Fourth</option><option value="social_top">Social Top</option><option
value="search_form">Search Form</option><option
value="logo">Logo</option><option value="menu">Menu</option><option
value="strapline_first">Strapline</option><option
value="latest_first">Latest Work</option><option
value="sidebar_first">Sidebar First</option><option
value="sidebar_second">Sidebar Second</option><option
value="postcontent_first">Post Content First</option><option
value="team_first">Team First</option><option
value="logoslider_first">Logo Slider First</option><option
value="bottom_first">Bottom First</option><option
```

Every page refresh is different.

Anyone have any ideas?

I have a custom module or two, but I don't think they are doing anything bad.  We haven't touched the theme. I've cleared Drupal's cache.  I can't see anything relevant in Drupal's log or the PHP error log.  Every other admin page works fine.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it working.  This is what I did: I restarted Windows.